# Calculate values in LEFT JOIN inside UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine multiple MySQL statements into a single one. Below is what I've come up with:

```
UPDATE users 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity_profileviews WHERE puid = 2 AND date > 100000) AS total_profileviews
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT from_id) AS total_messages FROM messages WHERE to_id = 2 AND time_sent > 100000) AS total_messages
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS total_favorites FROM favorites WHERE favorite_uid = 2 AND date > 100000) AS total_favorites 
SET users.popularity = (total_profileviews + (total_messages * 10) + (total_favorites * 5)) 
WHERE id = 2
```

MySQL is giving me the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET users.popularity = (total_profileviews + (total_messages * 10) + (total_favo' at line 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Ok, it took a while but here's what I came up with. Is this the best way to accomplish this? Seems like it could be optimized a bit better.

```
UPDATE
    users 
SET
    users.popularity = (
        SELECT
            (total_profileviews + (total_messages * 10) + (total_favorites * 5)) AS new_popularity
        FROM
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_profileviews FROM activity_profileviews WHERE puid = 2 AND date > 100000) t1,
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT from_id) AS total_messages FROM messages WHERE to_id = 2 AND time_sent > 100000) t2,
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS total_favorites FROM favorites WHERE favorite_uid = 2 AND date > 100000) t3
    )
WHERE
    users.id = 2
```

Comment: BTW, (in the absence of a NULL condition) an OUTER JOIN on an UPDATE seems kind of strange to me. And you're not saying what you're JOINing ON. When preparing tricky updates, I think it's good to start with the SELECT query that returns the equivalent result, and then try to adapt that to an UPDATE.

Comment: I'm trying to put together a SELECT statement now that returns the same thing and that's not going too well either. The problem is I don't understand subqueries well enough. I'll keep trying to get this working and see if I get anywhere :)

Comment: Here's what I've gotten as far as a SELECT statement http://pastebin.com/JNuiH4CG The subqueries all work, but the part where I'm trying to actually do calculations with the variables from the subquery returns the MySQL error "Unknown column 'total_profileviews' in 'field list'".

Comment: Now might be a good time to familiarise yourself with sqlfiddle. ;-) And remember, just build it up step-by-step, so start with users, then add activity_profileviews. When that's working, add messages, etc.

Comment: @Gavin Your alias names are names for derived tables, not column alias names. If you've got names for columns try to get the calculated value in a SELECT statement (as said by Strawberry). Have a look at the manual chapter [Problems with column aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html) too.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I got an update query working and added it in an edit to the original post. I know there's probably a better way to do this. At least it's working though :)

Comment: Not sure I'd want to add this one to the MySQL canon

Comment: I'd appreciate any suggestions...